# 2D Arrays Battleship place random ships

Tags: java, arrays

**Hi, I just started to create a battleship game and I would like to know how to place random ships in my 2D Array. Here is the code for 2D Array.**

```
public class javaapplication24 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] table = new int[10][10];
        int i,j,k;
        for(i=0;i<table.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<table.length;j++){
                System.out.print(table[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add more tags to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have undoubtedly noticed is that as each ship is placed, it rules out possibilities of where subsequent ships can be placed. The easiest way around the difficulty is just trial and error. First write a function for randomly placing a ship of a given size somewhere on the board. Place the ships using a nested loop. The outer loop could be a for-loop which iterates through the ships to be placed. The inner loop can be a while loop (or maybe a do-loop) that repeatedly calls the ship-placing function to get a candidate placement, then checks if it clashes with previous choices, looping until a clash-free placement is found.

As far as placing a single ship goes:

1) First generate a random number which is either 0 or 1 to determine if the ship will be placed horizontally or vertically

2) Then pick a random number to determine what the row or column it will be in

3) Finally, pick a random number for the first square in the row or column that contains the ship. The size of the ship will enter in here. If it has length 3, for example, then there are only 10-3 = 7 possible choices for the first square (assuming a standard 10x10 board).

On Edit: @Manus raised a good point about difficulties that would be encountered if the number of ships are above a certain threshold. If you have a massive fleet of ships on a small board it is possible that certain partial placements (of some of the ships) would rule out any valid placement of the remaining ships. The only way I see around this difficulty is to use a back-tracking approach that checks if there is enough room for a ship before trying to place it and, if not, revisit the placement of previous ships until you get something that works. But -- the work involved in checking if there is any valid position can be done in such a way that you simultaneously determine the set of valid positions, in which case you might as well directly pick from that set rather than use trial and error. My approach is essentially a quick-and-dirty approach for simulating the child's game. You would need a more sophisticated approach if you want a more flexible game.

Comment: @Bob__ That might be a good idea. On the other hand, smaller ships placed earlier would rule out less positions for ships that come later. I don't have a strong intuition about which way would be better. It would be interesting to try both approaches and see which one requires fewer attempts. From a practical point of view it probably doesn't really matter, since I don't think either approach would require many trials.

Comment: I belive that less positions for ships that come later means more unsuccesful attempts. But it would be better testing, of course.

Comment: If you have a lot of ships, you might end up with no possible location for the last ship. Your answer should include a solution for this situation (now, it would end up in an infinite loop).

Comment: You could run a monte carlo simulation on this once you're done to see if any cells are more or less likely to have a ship on them, but I'm not sure if having a ship along an edge is a good strategy or not.

Comment: @Manu: That's why I propose starting with the longest ships. The 1 block ships will always find a place

Comment: @Manu That is either a very good point or it is irrelevant. In the standard version of the game the parameters are such that it is simply impossible to place all but one of the ships in such a way that the last ship can't be placed. Since OP hardwired in a 10x10 grid (the standard size) I assumed that they had a standard 5-ship scenario in mind. There is no simple tweak of my algorithm that would apply to non-standard versions of the game. It would require at the very least a back-tracking approach.

Comment: @Bob__ You are definitely right that if you are trying to fill a crowded board then the longest-to-shortest heuristic is a good optimization. With the sort of sparser board I had in mind it becomes a little less clear-cut, although even there I suspect that you are probably correct.